# How can I check if a function is always $\ge 0$ for all values of its parameter $\ge 0$?

Tags: functions

Let's say I have a function with with arbitrary coefficients and powers, something like $f(x) = 5x^2 - 7x^3 + x^4$.

How can I check if this function is always $\ge 0\ \forall x \ge 0$? The procedure is something I'm going to encode in Python.

Comment: What kind of function do you have? Does it need to be a polynomial function?

Comment: I take it your functions are polynomials in one variable. If so then you are looking at the classical problem of isolating the roots of a real polynomial.  If you google for "root isolation" or "sSurm's theorem" you will find some pointers. In practice, numerical (approximate) methods may be more useful to you - it depends on the practical problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Sorry about the typo: I mean "Sturm's theorem". Coding this kind of thing up for yourself will be a lot of work - so you might like to look in to a computer algebra system like http://www.sagemath.org to do the work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Finding the roots, especially with polynomials but more widely with continuous functions, will allow you to have only a few cases to check (basically $n + 1$, $n$ being the number of roots). For this you can use Newton's method for instance.

For instance here you can factor your polynomial with $x^2$ ($0$ is a 'double' root), and you have $2$ other roots which let you determine whether or not this polynomial is positive with only 3 'if's.

This can even be more shortened because you only need positive roots, and for a polynomial you can have the sign in $0^+$ and $+\infty$ even more easily (as it is the sign of respectively the lowest and highest degree coefficient).

Answer (score 1):

You can try and arbitrary point to see if the function is ever positive. If it is, then try and solve $f(x) = 0$ to see if your function ever crosses the x axis (which means it could go negative in that vicinity). Algorithms which solve such equations are called 'root finding' techniques. I think for an arbitrary polynomial the task is pretty difficult.

Answer (score 1):

By hand you would state the inequality $f(x) \ge 0$ and would try to solve for $x$. For arbitrary polynomials $P(x)$ this is not possible.
So you would need to rely on numerical methods.

You start with $P(0)$ and if that one is positive it will stay positive until it hits a root, thus an argument value $x_1$ with $P(x_1) = 0$. From $x_1$ on you need to check, if $P$ continues with negative values.

For polynomials the fundamental theorem of algebra tells one that a (non constant) polynomial of highest power $n$ has $n$ complex roots (a root might show up several times, like $x=0$ in your example twice), and thus $n$ or less real roots. You could try to determine these roots one by one. 
So the procedure is finite.

Comment: actually, the theory of polynomials over the real field is decidable.

Comment: @RobArthan Can you elaborate how that helps? You mean more than having a root fallen from heaven and inserting it, I hope. :-)

Comment: it helps by showing that there are known algorithms that solve the OP's problem. Root isolation for univariate polynomials (which is probably all that is relevant here) is a classical problem with a long literature that I leave you to find out for yourself. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field#Model_theory:_decidability_and_quantifier_elimination for some more detailed information on the general case.